# Match function with dates

Tags: excel

I have date column on two different sheets and when I run a match function (part of index match) it comes up N/A, because Excel says the two cells that have the same date in them are not equal to each other. When I change the format of one of the columns it changes to five numbers (which I know that is what excel uses to track dates), but the other column does not do this, it is simply text.

My question is, how to I get excel to forget about the five number date format and just give me text? Paste special values doesn't get it done like I thought it would.

Comment: I'd go with the real date format that @Burgertron suggests - then `01/12/2020` will be the same as `01-Dec-20`.  Before cutting the string up though try multiplying it by 1. `=A1*1`.  I find more often than not that this is enough to convert a text date into a real date.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you basically have two options: either convert both to text, or convert both to dates. If you want the text, the easiest way to convert them to text is via text to columns:

1. Select the column with the date (the one that turns to a 5 digit number when formatted to number or general) and select Text to Columns:

   [image]
2. Click on next twice and select Text, then finish:

   [image]

And that should do it.

---

I'll mention the other method, just in case, because in my experience, it's more often more practical to get the dates as actual dates in excel rather than text, especially when one wants to perform calculation on them or allow for different date formats.

1. The other method involves inserting 1 somewhere and copying it. Then select the set of dates that is plain text:

   [image]
2. Use the paste special function and select 'Multiply' under the operations section:

   [image]

All the dates normally should turn into those 5 digit numbers (if they were originally formatted as general for example). You simply then need to format them as date with the appropriate format, and your index/match should be fine matching the two date columns.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will struggle to compare text (date as text) with numbers (date as an integer).

My suggestion is to convert the text into a 'proper' date.  This is a good habit. When excel recognises something as a date it will store it as that 5-digit integer, but can display it however you choose (format cells to see the options)

So create a column next to your 'text dates'.  Fill it with a formula which will create a 'proper' date, using the existing text.
If your text is in A1, then put this in B1. Assuming your data is dd/mm/yyyy 
    `=date(right(a1,4),mid(a1,4,2),left(a1,2))`
This is just saying that:

- Year = rightmost 4 characters
- Month= middle 2 digits (start at character 4 and grab 2 digits)
- Day = leftmost 2 digits.

I assume you are using normal dates, and not the abomination that is USA format dates. But if your text is in USA data format then just swap the month and day parameters. Likewise if your text dates are 2 digits just tweak the 'year' parameter.

Check it works as expected, then copy down the column.  You can now use column B for your vlookup or index match.

nb **Jerry's answer is excellent and should work**. I added the above because it tells you a little about how to directly work with dates.  Good luck.